# React-native iOS Bridging module in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, react-native, npm

I would like to create a native module in order to use it in my react-native project. The particularity is that I want to use the Swift language.

So I created a fresh RN project using **react-native init** command.

Here's my packages dependencies :

- RN (0.59.5)
- React (16.8.3)

I created a directory inside my **node_modules** directory called react-native-hello-world in order to 1) train with a simple example 2) mock my future Npm package.

Inside this directory I created my HelloWorld.xcodeproj.

```
-- nodes_modules
   -- react-native-hello-world
      -- ios/
         -- HelloWorld/
            -- HelloWorld.xcodeproj
            -- HelloWorld/
               -- HelloWorld.swift
               -- HelloWorld-Bridging-Header.h
```

As I mentioned I want to create this module using Swift. So I used XCode to create a bridging header file as RN documentation says.

That's when my problems started ... When I add

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>
```

In my HelloWorld-Bridging-Header.h file an error occurs and say **'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found**.

I tried to clean my project and even delete my derived data but I still have this error.

I even added in my target's header search path React's .h files.

```
$(SRCROOT)/../../../react-native/React  //recursive
```

But I still have this error ... I don't understand why, in my opinion I did everything I had to do right. so maybe we can't create a native module using Swift ?

Could someone tell me if I made a mistake or if they've already managed to tell me how to do it?

Some help would be really appreciated,

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only **peer dependencies** and try open **HelloWorld.xcodeproj** (As i understand that this is your module) it will not working, because you don't have node_modules into your custom_module folder.

1. a) Added this module to your main project **package.json**

   "dependencies": {
       "react-native-hello-world": "file:custom_modules/RNHelloWorld",
       ...
       }
2. npm install
3. Open your **PROJECT_NAME/ios/PROJECT_NAME.xcodeproj**
4. As you can see your RNHelloWorld added to your ***Libraries***
5. You can start working with your custom module here and error with **RCTBridgeModule** will dissapear, because you have **libReact.a** into your **Link Library with Binaries**

Comment: Indeed it works when I add my module's xcodeproj to my RN project's libraries. But, in order to complete the answer, could you tell me if it does make sense to build my module standalone. I explain myself, let's say I don't want to create a RN project only to test my future module. Can I declare react-native as dev dependencies inside my module's package.json and do the same process as you described ?

Comment: Yes, you can add RN to devDependencies and npm install. After npm install check, that you have in Link LIbrary with Binaries RN libs. If you don't have RN libs you can added them manually.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Hardy1207 ! By the way in order to use a bridge module written in Swift you must also have a Bridging-Header.h file inside your main application + a dummy swift file. Otherwise you will get an error.